# CP assets uploads are reverse ordered after upload

Tags: assets, control-panel, upload

## Problem

CP assets uploads are reverse ordered after upload.

## Description

I have a folder with 5 images:

- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg
- 3.jpg
- 4.jpg
- 5.jpg

I want to upload these images in the Craft CP. I have an Asset field and add the images by clicking the ‘Add an asset’ button. When I'm done the order of the images in the field is:

- 5.jpg
- 4.jpg
- 3.jpg
- 2.jpg
- 1.jpg

## Example

Before upload:

[image]

After upload:

[image]

## Question

Is there a way to upload assets in the same order?

Comment: How were you uploading them? Drag and drop to a field? Clicking the asset select button? Was your file picker on your computer set to reverse chronological?

Comment: I'm using the asset select button.

Answer (score 1):

Did some more tests. In my finder I have two files:

- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg

When I upload these files, 1.jpg is uploaded first and 2.jpg second. In the control panel 2.jpg is the latest uploaded file and therefore the first visible asset. This clarifies the reversed order.

A little trick when uploading multiple files from the finder and keeping the same order, is to reverse the file order in the finder (start with Z and end with names starting with A).